My beamer theme with ignorenonframetext option goes into emergency stop unless I specify \mode<presentation>
This code, that uses the default Madrid theme, compiles correctly:
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usetheme[]{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}

However, using my university's beamer theme, it goes into emergency stop:
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usetheme[]{UNIBO_NEW_3}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}

It works if I specify \mode<presentation> at the beginning:
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usetheme[]{UNIBO_NEW_3}

\begin{document}
\mode<presentation>
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}

Or if I don't use the ignorenonframetext beamer option:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[]{UNIBO_NEW_3}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}

which I have to use because it's put in automatically by Quarto.
Why is that?
Is there something wrong with my theme?
Here are the .sty files of my theme, which came to me under a GPL license.
The associated PDF files came without a license so I'm not comfortable sharing them.
beamercolorthemeUNIBO_NEW_3.sty
% Copyright 2004 by Madhusudan Singh <madhusudan.singh@gmail.com>  Modified by Emanuele Bacchiega, 2010, 2018, 2024
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%

\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.7,0.1,0.1}

\definecolor{lightred}{RGB}{240,128,128}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=darkred, bg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=darkred, bg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=darkred!80!gray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=darkred!60!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=darkred!70!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{fg=darkred!10!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=darkred!25!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{fg=darkred!40!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=darkred!70!white}

%\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{fg=darkred}

\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{fg=gray}

\mode<all>

beamerinnerthemeUNIBO_NEW_3.sty
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau, Moified by Emanuele Bacchiega, 2018, 2024
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{FIRST_NEW_3.pdf}
%\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{last}{LAST_NEW.pdf}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

        \begin{picture}(0,0)

            \put(-32,-157.5){
                \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
            }

            \put(125,-110.7){
                \begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{65mm}
                \setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
                %\setbeamerfont{institute}{\tiny}
                \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=darkred}
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}
                    \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}\vspace{5mm}
                    \usebeamerfont{author}{\insertauthor\par}\vspace{5mm}
                    \usebeamerfont{institute}{\insertinstitute\par}
                    \vspace{5mm}
                    \insertdate
                \end{minipage}
            }

            \end{picture}

    }

  

\mode<all>

beamerthemeUNIBO_NEW_3
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau, Modified by Emanuele Bacchiega, 2010, 2018, 2024
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]
\usecolortheme{UNIBO_NEW_3}
\useinnertheme{UNIBO_NEW_3}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
                   height=\paperheight]{SLIDES_NEW_3.pdf}
}

% Per personalizzare la pagina finale, decommentare e modificare le righe qui sotto.

 \setbeamertemplate{endpage}{
 
     \usebackgroundtemplate{
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{LAST_NEW_3.pdf}}
 \begin{frame}
%   \vspace{10mm}
% \begin{center}
%   Nome Cognome \\\vspace{5mm} Dipartimento di Rocket Science\\\vspace{5mm }\href{mailto:nome.cognome@unibo.it}{\texttt{nome.cognome@unibo.it}}
% \end{center}
 \end{frame}}
 
 \AtEndDocument{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\mode<all>


Note to self: as a workaround, use
include-before-body:      text: "\\mode<presentation>"
in Quarto

You could boil your example down to `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\AtEndDocument{
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
`

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Looks like the core of an answer to me

@JosephWright I need to think a bit more about if there is a nice way to avoid this

Following @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz lead, commenting out \AtEndDocument{\usebeamertemplate{endpage}} in the theme make the document compile without emergency stops.
